# Globally disabling non-Animator animations for Espresso testing

Tags: android, animation, testing, android-espresso, ui-testing

I'm currently developing a UI test suite in Espresso for an app which has many procedural animations thorough. Many of those animations are actually infinitely-looped, which makes Espresso hang indefinitely while waiting for idleness.

Now, unfortunately, those animations were not developed using the Animator library classes, so the usual way of turning off animation scale (through Developer Settings) yields no effect here. At the same time, the dev team is wary about adding test-related code into the application's code (which prevents me from using flags/environment variables to manually stop animations, for instance).

Is there a solution to globally disable all animations regardless of their implementation without adding code into the application when running UI tests?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: it's been a while and I learned a bit about test automation since then. so my current take is that it's not possible to do that at all without touching application code (gladly I managed to convince devs to allow me to do that). the reason being that it's not possible for the system to be aware of all arbitrary code that might be changing layout settings over time, thus creating animations. does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah it does, thank you. I guess I'll have to do the same and re-implement my animations if I wanna get testing to work properly.

Comment: if your animations are not essential for the app to work normally, you can add a flag to the BuildConfig class and use it to conditionally run the animations. then you set that flag to true/false when you want to run Espresso tests

Answer (score -1):

Best solution I've been able to find so far is using the command line to turn off device animations before test execution. Ie. make a small shell script that executes these commands

adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0

Comment: As mentioned in the question, turning off animation scale yields no effect